# Grails: how to return error message from controller logic (i.e. not originating from domain property validation)?

Tags: grails, view, error-handling, controller

Errors e.g. with bad user input can not always be reasonably checked using domain or command object validation.

E.g. when creating a "forgot password" functionality, I want to show an adequate message if the user enters a username which is not present in the database. So the controller action does something like this

```
...
def user = User.find{name==uname}
if(!user) {
    // user not found in db, output error and render view again
    render view: 'forgotPassword'
    return
}
// do reset password stuff
...
```

What should I do to display the error in the view within the `<g:hasErros>` tag?

`flash.message` (as the generated controllers/views do it) does not seem right to me, because I am not merely displaying an info message, but an error message. That's why I think the message should be handled by the `<g:hasErros>` tag and displayed like a domain validation error. (To the user, it is the same feedback level: "did not work due to bad input".

Creating a `@Validateable` command object does not seem right, too. IMHO, checking a value against the database is not actually the responsibility of validation within a command object? Or is it? Then it seems to be a little too complex to me.

So what is the best way to go? Other frameworks (e.g. Wicket) provide distinct methods like `error(String msg)` and `info(String msg)` which allow easy handling of feedback messages in the view. Is there a similar concept in Grails, which I just have not found yet?

Comment: For those who are interested in the final solution I have built upon the input of Burt beckwith and Ian Robers: unfortunately I am not allowed to publish the source code, but in general I simply created a TagLib with two members: #1 to write add a message to the flash scope, e.g. `myproject.message(error:'User does not exist')` or `myproject.message(success:'Password changed')`

Comment: All msgs are added two one of four lists in `flash`, according to their type (error/success/warning/info). Member #2 is the actual tag to display messages, rendering all msgs into the page. It also retrieves flash.message and bean errors. Hope this helps

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`flash` is just a Map and you can put whatever you want in it - strings, numbers, objects, etc. It's convenient since it only lasts one request, so it only temporarily pollutes the session. The convention in the generated GSPs is to use the `message` key, but it's just a convention.

If you want to store another message, store it in a different key:

```
flash.warning = '...'
```

or

```
flash.error = '...'
```

and retrieve it in the GSP like the other message.

Comment: Indeed, this is the approach I use on my projects - I define a taglib that handles `flash.message`, `flash.warning` and `flash.error` and then I just have to put `<g:flashMessages/>` in my view/scaffolding template/layout.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about `flash` being a Map :) That would work for the example case, but what would do if e.g. you needed a combination, e.g. the possibility to output two error messages from the controller plus more from "classic" domain validation?

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for your input... seems to be a good idea to write a taglib for this - if I taught it to handle what's inside `<g:haserrors>` too, this might be the best solution for my use case... And I could probably put a list of error msgs into `flash` instead of just one... Should work.... I will try this.

Comment: Just did some testing, I think this approach is going to work, and it's cleaner than everything I found while researching the web. Thanks to both of you for your valuable input :)